# @WithMockUser in a parallel context

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, spring-test

The following code is just a simplified version of what I want to achieve.

I am using `@WithMockUser(username = "jane@no-domain.com", authorities = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})` to mock a user in my tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAsync
@WithMockUser(username = "jane@no-domain.com", authorities = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})
public class NonTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        IntStream.range(1, 10)
            .parallel() // Comment this and it will work
            .forEach(value -> {
                getUser(value);
            });
    }

    public void getUser(int value) {
        System.out.println(value + ": " + ((User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername());
    }

}
```

When I execute the above code with `.parallel()` commented out, it works and prints out the following as intended:

```
1: jane@no-domain.com
2: jane@no-domain.com
3: jane@no-domain.com
4: jane@no-domain.com
5: jane@no-domain.com
6: jane@no-domain.com
7: jane@no-domain.com
8: jane@no-domain.com
9: jane@no-domain.com
```

... but when I add the `.parallel()` it throws a `NullPointerException` since somehow the mocked user is not present.

It behaves the same way when I use an `ExecutorService` or any threading of some sort.

So, how do I execute the method in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `.parallel()` will spawn multiple threads to run over the stream in parallel. From the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel) on streams:

> When a stream executes in parallel, the Java runtime partitions the
> stream into multiple substreams. Aggregate operations iterate over and
> process these substreams in parallel and then combine the results.

So you need to make the children threads inherit the `SecurityContextHolder` from the local thread, for this you could use `@PostConstruct` as follows, (see more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations)):

```
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAsync
@WithMockUser(username = "jane@no-domain.com", authorities = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})
public class NonTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        IntStream.range(1, 10)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(this::getUser);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void setGlobalSecurityContext() {
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    }

    public void getUser(int value) {
        System.out.println(value + ": " + ((User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
6: jane@no-domain.com
7: jane@no-domain.com
1: jane@no-domain.com
2: jane@no-domain.com
3: jane@no-domain.com
9: jane@no-domain.com
4: jane@no-domain.com
8: jane@no-domain.com
5: jane@no-domain.com
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I also learnt something. I didn't know that children threads should inherit the `SecurityContext` from the local thread.